# summarize Values und Multiple path Update Firebase Realtime Database with Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, database, firebase, dictionary

I've been trying to update a simple map with different entries.

I created first the const

```
const dMap: { [key: string]: any } = {};
```

and adding my Values:

```
dMap[urlToCurrentEvent] = updateMap
```

My Update Map show like :

```
const updateMap = {
  [new table.DB_artikel().anzahlVerfugbar()]: bestand,
  [new table.DB_artikel().visible()]: visible,
}
```

when i show it in console look like :

> 'karte/aktuell/34/artikel_inventar/34': { anzahlVerfugbar: 0, visible: false },
> 'karte/aktuell/34': { anzahlVerfugbar: 0, visible: false }

Thats fine and it seems to work, when i have different Paths, but now coms an error in updating Firebase :

> Error: update failed: values argument contains a path /karte/aktuell/34 that is ancestor of another path /karte/aktuell/34/artikel_inventar/34

I am understood , but was is the resolution?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to perform these two updates in one go:

```
'karte/aktuell/34/artikel_inventar/34': { 
  anzahlVerfugbar: 0, 
  visible: false 
}
'karte/aktuell/34': { 
  anzahlVerfugbar: 0, 
  visible: false 
}
```

But that first path is a child of the second path, so the order of the updates suddenly matters here - and that is not allowed in a multipath update.

To make this explicit, if we execute the updates in the order above, we end up with:

```
karte: {
  aktuell: {
    '34': { 
      anzahlVerfugbar: 0, 
      visible: false 
    }
  }
}
```

But if we execute them in the reverse order, we end up with:

```
karte: {
  aktuell: {
    '34': { 
      anzahlVerfugbar: 0, 
      visible: false,
      artikel_inventar: {
        anzahlVerfugbar: 0, 
        visible: false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Since this means the update becomes non-deterministic, the data rejects the operation.

If you want that last result, you should send a single path update:

```
'karte/aktuell/34': { 
  anzahlVerfugbar: 0, 
  visible: false,
  artikel_inventar: { 
    '34': {
      anzahlVerfugbar: 0, 
      visible: false 
    }
  }
}
```

I'd also recommend reading the Firebase documentation on [structuring data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data), specifically the section on [avoiding nests](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#avoid_nesting_data), as this is a common cause of these problems.

Comment: My attempt to nest the data fails every time, what came closest was:
    dMap[pathi] = {
              updateMap,
              [new table.DB_artikel_inventar().DbName_artikel_inventar()]: {
                [idInventar]: updateMap
              }
            }

i get:
      dMap {
    'karte/aktuell/34': {
      updateMap: { anzahlVerfugbar: 0, visible: false },
      artikel_inventar: { '34': [Object] }
    }}
What is the correct syntax for taypescript that I can use to merge maps..

That means a few foreach loops are run through, collected, and then I just want an entry...